# Unity crashes each time I run this script

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I believe it has something to do with the while, because if I remove it it works fine.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Movement : MonoBehaviour {
public float speed = 1f;
public float pos = 0f;
void Start () {

}

void Update () {

    float temp = Input.acceleration.x;
    while (pos >= -200f && pos <= 200f){

        if (Input.touchCount > 0) {
            if ((Input.GetTouch (0).position.x >= 250)) { //Right
                transform.Rotate (0, 0, 0);
                pos += speed * 500 * Time.deltaTime;
                transform.Translate (speed * 500 * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0,   Space.World);
            } else if ((Input.GetTouch (0).position.x < 250)) { //Left
                transform.Rotate (0, 0, 0);
                pos -= speed * 500 * Time.deltaTime;
                transform.Translate (-speed * 500 * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0, Space.World);
                //Time.timeScale = 0.2F;

            }
        }
    }
    //Time.timeScale = 1F;
    transform.Rotate (0, 0, -temp * 500 * Time.deltaTime); //Rotation

    }
}
```

It's basically a script to control a cube using the android accelerometer and the touchscreen. It works fine, but when I implement the while to "bound" the movement it crashes whenever I play it.

Comment: If a loop crashes it most likely doesn't stop (= infinite loop). This is bad, even more since it runs in a function that it self basically loops (Update).  This means that the game gets stuck in an infinite loop in a frame and the game can't progress. Why does this need to be a `while`? Shouldn't a simple `if` do it?

Comment: Try using a [coroutine](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html) instead

Comment: Thanks for the aswers! I'm quite noob at programming :D

Answer (score 4):

You shouldn't use a `while` loop in `Update`, because `Update` is your game loop. This essentially stops the game from updating because it's trapped in your loop and can never render the next frame. Try using an `if` statement in place of your `while` to produce your desired effect.

Answer (score 0):

Just to rephrase lase:

Update runs as long as your game is running and it only run on active GameObjects.
Therefore you should NOT use a While Loop in an update function.

Use:

```
if (pos >= -200f && pos <= 200f){

}
```